# UseRef element is null

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, use-ref

I'm  coding a conditional render that uses an UseRef hook.
After setting the useState to false, I'm trying to get the element of into the UseRef to set some css Properties but it always returns me null.
I see that  it happens probably because since the element has not  been rendered yet in the condition .

```
function Cover() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('Rdn');
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams({ cover: query });
  const [bgImageLoaded, setBgImageLoaded] = useState(true);
  const image = `/images/covers/mobile/${query}.jpg`;
  const element = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    const querystring = new URLSearchParams(document.location.search);
    const q = querystring.get('cover');
    if (q !== null) {
      setQuery(q);
    }

    SetBgImage();
  }, []);
  const SetBgImage = () => {
    load(image).then(() => {
      setBgImageLoaded(false);
      setTimeout(() => {
        element.current.style.backgroundImage = `url(${image})`;
      }, 1000);
    });
  };

  function load(src) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const image = new Image();
      image.addEventListener('load', resolve);
      image.addEventListener('error', reject);
      image.src = src;
    });
  }

  if (bgImageLoaded) {
    return <span>loading...</span>;
  } else {
    switch (query) {
      case 'Rdn':
        return (
          <section 
    className={classList('Cover', query)}
      ref={element}
      >
           
          </section>
        );
    }
  }
  // eslint-disable-next-line default-case
}

export default Cover;
```

Comment: You are never assigning the 'element' ref in your code with some value. Did you forget to supply the 'element' value to a DOM element via the 'ref' prop?

Comment: You either need to assign a value at some point via element.current = somevalue or attach the 'element' reference to a DOM element via the ref={current} prop.

Comment: Thanks. Apparently  it works ! But not so much... Some the rendering is sometimes it returns me the error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: element.current is null

Comment: The idea behind the Ref is that you must supply a value for it at some point, via the .current property or via the ref={} prop. Neither happens in your code, hence it will always be null. Perhaps you need to update the code with the 'element' ref being supplied a value. That's the element.current NOT the element.current.style.

Comment: Do you mean the  "ref={element}" line?

Comment: did you try to change from ref={element} to ref={(ref) => element = ref}

Comment: Why should this work?